# Angular JS, different display of dependent lists on desktop and mobile

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design

I have 3 nested list that i display in the same screen in desktop (image below) when i select movies, i display the movies list, when i select a movie, i display the movies actors.

[image]

I want to display this lists in sepereted screens on mobile. What is the best way to do this? thx

[image]

Comment: check for the user agent and depending on desktop or mobile create different routes i dont think there is a good angular way for doing what you want within one view

Comment: Now that i think about it you could also just display the first list on mobile and after klick just remove the first and call the next list smth like that but this maybe a performance problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [ngInclude](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). You could have the same 3 template files loaded for each of the menus and transition them out for mobile. The example in the link should give you an idea for the mobile transitions.